# To set the owner property for WPF window

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, autodesk

I am Working on creating addin for Autodesk Inventor,  I have class lib project in that I will show a wpf window on button click, that works great.  However, I could not set the owner property for my window..  In my research I came to know that we need to get the parent window object..

Comment: *I could not set the owner property for my window*... why not? What's wrong with `window.Owner = windowParent?`You need to explain your problem further.

Comment: with the window.Owner we can set,  but I am not able to get the Parent window (Inventor Application) in this to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not able to get parent window, you can try setting the parent using window handle.

I'm not familiar with Autodesk Inventor and how you create plugin for the application so I don't know if you can get window handle but I guess you could know process id or window caption/title or some other information that can help you get the parent window handle (you should Google how to get window handle). Once you have handle of parent window you can set it as an owner of your window using WindowInteropHelper.

Here's just a sample how to use WindowInteropHelper:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IntPtr parentWindowHandler = IntPtr.Zero;
        // I'll just look for notepad window so I can demonstrate (remember to run notepad before running this sample code :))
        foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Notepad"))
            {
                parentWindowHandler = pList.MainWindowHandle;
                break;
            }
        }

        var interop = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        interop.EnsureHandle();
        // this is it
        interop.Owner = parentWindowHandler;

        // i'll use this to check if owner is set
        // if it's set MainWindow will be shown at the center of notepad window
        WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just reiterating the example that user1018735 gave. I develop Inventor Add-ins so I modified the code above to make sure I am always working with the correct Inventor session since multiple instances of Inventor can be open at once. I do this by passing my already known application object to my form through the _App parameter; then since the process MainWindowTitle is always the same as the applications caption I match the two.

I'm running this in a WPF Class Library @ VB.Net 4.5.1. 
Here is a peek at my code that works in Inventor 2014...

```
Public Sub New(ByVal _App As Inventor.Application)

    'This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    'Find the Inventor Window Handle.
    Dim InvWndHnd As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    'Search the process list for the matching Inventor application.
    For Each pList As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
        If pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(_App.Caption) Then
            InvWndHnd = pList.MainWindowHandle
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Dim InvWndIrp = New WindowInteropHelper(Me)
    InvWndIrp.EnsureHandle()
    InvWndIrp.Owner = InvWndHnd

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a window and make this window its owner
Window ownedWindow = new Window();
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.Show();
```